# Textbox text to listbox items vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Ok so i have a textbox that gets items from a website and pastes in that then the list box adds the items but i want each line in textbox to be a new item instead it just adds it all as one

heres my code

```
    '  Procedure:
    Dim Str As System.IO.Stream
    Dim srRead As System.IO.StreamReader
    Try
        ' make a Web request
        Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://76.31.248.130/videos.txt")
        Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse
        Str = resp.GetResponseStream
        srRead = New System.IO.StreamReader(Str)
        ' read all the text 
        TextBox2.Text = srRead.ReadToEnd
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBox2.Text = "Unable to download content"
    Finally
        '  Close Stream and StreamReader when done
        srRead.Close()
        Str.Close()
    End Try
    ' Assign string to reference.
    Dim value1 As String = TextBox2.Text


    ' Replace word with another word.
    Dim value2 As String = value1.Replace("<br>", vbNewLine)
    TextBox2.Text = value2
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox2.Text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very hard to understand.  I think the answer is to split the textbox's text into an array where each item is a single line and then add each of these to the listbox.

You probably want:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TextBox2.Text.Split(vbNewLine))
```

Answer (score 0):

ITS AS SIMPLE AS 
  ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)) oR
  ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TextBox1.Text.Split(vbcrlf)

Answer (score 0):

try using `srRead.readline` instead of `srRead.readtoend`

```
Dim a As String
Try
        Do
            a = srRead.ReadLine
            If a <> Nothing Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(a)
            End If
        Loop Until a Is Nothing
    Catch
    End Try
```

Sorry if i failed to understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TextBox2.Lines)
```

instead of

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox2.Text)
```