# VB.NET - how i can split all listbox items that contain "text" to other list

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, split, listbox

i have listbox1 that include :

```
ListBox1.Items.Add("https://myweb.com/#questionsquestions/4444444/x/testxx")
ListBox1.Items.Add("https://translate.google.com/#questions/HAHAHAHA/testxx")
ListBox1.Items.Add("https://translate.google.com/#questions/HAHAHAHA/testxx")
ListBox1.Items.Add("http://stackexchange.com/")
ListBox1.Items.Add("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304084/how-to-remove-text-from-a-list-box")
ListBox1.Items.Add("http://stackoverflow.com/users/2227126/abdullah-kassha")
ListBox1.Items.Add("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860214/vb-net-split-string")
ListBox1.Items.Add("#")
ListBox1.Items.Add("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808080/categorize-listbox-items-by-color")
ListBox1.Items.Add("")
ListBox1.Items.Add("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073532/textbox-text-to-listbox-items-vb-net")
ListBox1.Items.Add("questiooonsquestions/ID_3324244/v")
ListBox1.Items.Add("cccccquestions/ID_3324244/RNA")
ListBox1.Items.Add("cccccquestions/ID_9999999/RNA")
```

I want to split or get the text between `"questions/"` and `"/"` without any empty or duplicate items

example picture :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiZ9E.png

Comment: any attempts so far? and maybe read up on [split](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet)

Comment: @jbutler483 of course yes i tried, i have split string list to ComboBox but the string not contain empty or duplicate items but can't do same in listbox and in this way / ˢᵒʳʳʸ ᶠᵒʳ ᵐʸ ᵇᵃᵈ ᵉᶰᵍˡᶤˢʰ ᶤᵗˢ ᶰᵒᵗ ᵐʸ ᵐᵒᵗʰᵉʳ ˡᵃᶰᵍᵘᵃᵍᵉ

Comment: how are they being added to the ListBox? Could you not test this whenever the next value is being entered? (using a foreach element in ListBox?) and checking if it already contains the value? also if value isn't ""?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a super simple project and put this Function in the main class:

```
Public Function Simon(ByVal x As String) As String
        Try
            Return Split(Split(x, "questions/")(1), "/")(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ""
        End Try
End Function
```

Also, put a cute `Button` and put this code into it

```
For Each y As String In ListBox1.Items
        If Not ListBox2.Items.Contains(simon(y)) And Not simon(y) = "" Then
        Dim smo As String = simon(y)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(smo)
        End If
Next
```

Result:

```
4444444
HAHAHAHA
23304084
7860214
25808080
7073532
ID_3324244
ID_9999999
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
Imports ystem.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Example:

```
Dim input As String = "cccccquestions/ID_9999999/RNA"
Dim re As New Regex("questions\/(.*)\/")
Dim m As Match = re.Match(input)
Dim id As String = m.Groups(1).Value 'yields "ID_9999999"
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ power and string methods:

```
Dim items = From i In listBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)()
            Let index = i.IndexOf("questions/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            Where index >= 0
            Let startIndex = index + "questions/".Length
            Let endIndex = i.IndexOf("/", startIndex)
            Where endIndex >= 0
            Select i.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)

listBox2.Items.AddRange(items.Distinct().ToArray())
```

Result:

```
4444444
HAHAHAHA
23304084
7860214
25808080
7073532
ID_3324244
ID_9999999
```